# Root of a negative real number - mistake in GRE Question?

Tags: roots, real-numbers

I already apologize for the banality of the question but I've come across the following GRE question and wanted to ask whether this is really a well-defined exercised.

One has to compare quantities and decide whether quantity A or quantity B is greater, whether they are equal or whether the relationship cannot be determined from the information given.

Here's the full question for completeness:

$$–1 < a < 0 < |a| < b < 1$$

Quantity A: $$\biggl(\frac{a^2\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}}\biggr)^2$$
Quantity B: $$\biggl(\frac{ab^5}{(\sqrt{b})^{4}}\biggr)$$

I am only curious about the denominator in quantity A, which I believe is not well defined since we are taking the square root of a negative number and $(\sqrt{a})^2 \neq \sqrt{a^2}$.

In the solution to the question in the GRE book they "use exponent rules" to simplify the expression to $\frac{a^4b}{a}$ and conclude that quantity A is greater. This seems so obviously wrong, have I missed something or is that a mistake in the question?

Comment: You are right: it is given that $\;a\;$ is negative so no way in the real numbers realm we can write $\;\sqrt a\;$, no matter what else we add afterwards. Now, for a non-negative number $\;c\;$ , it is true in the reals that $\;\left(\sqrt c\right)^2=\sqrt{c^2}=c\;$ .

Comment: I agree , since I assume we are in the reals. Then, it is forbidden to take the square root of a negative number. Rules do not apply if undefined objects appear in the formula.

Comment: should be $\biggl(\frac{a^2\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{|a|}}\biggr)^2$

Comment: Best case: complex numbers are allowed in GRE and the question is sloppy.  If $\sqrt{a}$ exists in $\mathbb C$  then it is some solution to $z^2 - a = 0$; so is $-\sqrt{a}$.  But they are equal under the image of the squaring map so the choice of sign does not matter here.  (Same idea with $\sqrt{b}$.)  Hence the question would read: for arbitrary valid choices of $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$, which quantity is greater.... but more likely @WillJagy is right here.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that all numbers in the GRE are real numbers, so no complex numbers allowed. Yep, I believe @WillJagy is right. Weird mistake nonetheless.